# a href background image display not working with chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

The problem only occurred when I added the a href which previously was just a div. I checked out the site in safari and everything is fine but when I opened it with chrome the background image turns into a grey box.

I read a question that says display: inline-block should fix it once the site is online so I updated my github but no luck! Any help with this would be much appreciated as I don't want to have to remove the background image.

Here is my github page ... https://michael-hands.github.io/jennielouise/

```
<a href="gallery.html" class="cake-smash">
   <div class="box1">
      <h2>Cake Smash</h2>
         <p class="animated">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
 </a>

.cake-smash
   position: relative
   height: 50%
   width: 100%
   display: block
   background-image: url("../img/cakesmash.jpg")
   background-position: center center
   background-repeat: no-repeat
   background-size: cover
   text-align: center
   display: inline-block
   margin-bottom: -5px
   padding: 0
```

Comment: The image [`cakesmash.jpg`](https://michael-hands.github.io/jennielouise/lib/img/cakesmash.jpg) seems to have errors. It's also might be unnecessarily large: 85.8MB.

Comment: @showdev do you have any explanations? it only occurs when I add the href

Comment: I can't view it even from a [direct link](https://michael-hands.github.io/jennielouise/lib/img/cakesmash.jpg), and I can't open it in PhotoShop either. I'd resize it, save it again, and re-upload.

Comment: @showdev I re-uploaded with a png file and it seems to work now thanks a bunch. Can tell im a newbie alright haha

Comment: Nice. Working here now, too :)